# Send dynamically updating data from python server to many clients

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading, multipoint

first I'll apologise if I've made some large error, I'm new to python.
I'm trying to write software using python sockets to generate a random number every 10 seconds and send it to multiple clients. So far I have been able to create a server and connect multiple clients, but the random numbers that are being generated and sent to each client are different. I'm trying to make them the same.

Here is my server code:

```
import sys, time, socket, threading, random

def newClient(c):
    global data
    c.send("Connected to stream".encode())
    while True:
        c.sendall(str(data).encode())
        time.sleep(10)

def setData():
    data = random.random()
    return data

def readData():
    global data
    while True:
        data = setData()

port = 12312
ssock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock.bind(('', port))
ssock.listen(5)

data = random.random()
threading.Thread(target=readData).start()

while True:
    c, addr = ssock.accept()
    print("[-] Connected to " + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))
    threading.Thread(target=newClient, args=(c,)).start()
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, so that my server sends the same data to both clients, I would be very grateful.

Comment: There's no synchronization between the threads so of course the numbers will be different

Comment: @xaav I think I understand that, but my question is how to create such synchronization

Comment: How about having a thread put random numbers into a queue and then fetching the numbers from the other threads?

Comment: @xaav I googled thread synxhronization in python (one of my issues was that I couldn't think of a way to describe my issue) and learnt about thread events, and I tried those out, now the numbers are mostly in sync, except sometimes they randomly change